# How to change style of openlayers control dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I am using an external panel (OpenLayers.Control.Panel) and i want to change the width of panel dynamically based on parameter. Is there any way to do this?

I tried

```
$('.olControlPanel').css('margin', '1000px');
```

But it doesnt bring any change to the panel

Please suggest if any other option is available

Comment: Use "inspect element" or similar in your browser, if you can change the css to suit your needs in there you'll be able to change it as above with jquery too.

Comment: I have already tried that out. In normal cases this code is supposed to work. But since i am using OpenLayers and the object i want to style is one of the openlayers component, there is some problem. The same code works for other html components though.

Comment: Well I see no reason for it not to, no jquery on [this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/jvanulden/openlayers/examples/extended-layerswitcher.html) but if you type `document.getElementsByClassName('olControlPanel')[0].style.top = "-100px"` the ControlPanel disappears off the top as expected. I'd need to see a jsfiddle of your code to provide any further insight.